# How to pass arguments to a function of arbitrary number of parameters via macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I have deconstructed **Function**, got it **vparams**, and now I am able to call:

```
  case class Action(f: Function, ts: List[TypeName]) {
    def render(ruleName: String): Expr[Unit] = c.Expr[Unit](q"""
      val p = ${c.prefix}
      val value1 = p.valueStack.pop().asInstanceOf[${ts(0)}]
      val value2 = p.valueStack.pop().asInstanceOf[${ts(1)}]
      p.valueStack.push($f(value1, value2))
    """)
  }
```

**f** is of arbitrary number of parameters that is known at compile time.

How to pass **ts.count** parameters from **p.valueStack** to a function **f**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
case class Action(f: Function, ts: List[TypeName]) {
  def render(ruleName: String): Expr[Unit] = {
    val argNames = (1 to ts.size).map(i => newTermName(s"value$i"))
    val args = argNames.map(name => Ident(name))
    val valDefs = (ts zip argNames).map {
      case (tn, argName) =>
        q"val $argName = p.valueStack.pop().asInstanceOf[$tn]"
    }

    c.Expr[Unit]( q"""
      val p = ${c.prefix}
      ..$valDefs
      p.valueStack.push($f(..$args))
      """)
  }
}
```

This compiles (in Scala 2.10.2 with Macro Paradise plugin), but I didn't test whether it works.

Comment: Eventually it does work. You can find the holy magic at [parboiled2 wip branch](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/commit/e6f0f51b6a13cabb713916855b37155dabedc8a0#L2R231)