# How to get a type in Scala AST of underscored lambda function parameter?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

Not digging in details of DSL, I could write ([based on that example](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/blob/wip/value-stack/examples/src/main/scala/org/parboiled2/examples/v2/SimpleCalculator1Runner.scala?source=c)):

```
def InputLine = rule { Number ~ zeroOrMore("+" ~ Number ~> ((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y)) ~ EOI }
```

I need to call lambda function from macro. Scala AST representation of it is as follows:

```
List(
   ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), newTermName("x"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Int)), EmptyTree), 
   ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), newTermName("y"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Int)), EmptyTree))
```

Important to note is that both **x** and **y** has types in AST. This works fine.

Next step is to use type inference, and simplify lambda as follows:

```
def InputLine = rule { Number ~ zeroOrMore("+" ~ Number ~> ((_:Int) + _)) ~ EOI }
```

Scala AST for that lambda:

```
List(
    ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM | SYNTHETIC), newTermName("x$1"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Int)), EmptyTree), 
    ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM | SYNTHETIC), newTermName("x$2"), TypeTree(), EmptyTree))
```

Note that **x$2** param has no explicit type. I need that to call the function. Where should I get it? The solution "just pass parameter of type **Any** to a function" will not satisfy **scalac** as it requires **Int**.

This question is logically followed by [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486977/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-function-of-arbitrary-number-of-parameters-via-macro/18487256?noredirect=1#18487256).

The code is available at [parboled2@gihub](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/blob/wip/value-stack/main/src/main/scala/org/parboiled2/OpTreeContext.scala?source=c#L65).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but have you tried type-checking the tree (or just that part of it) with `c.typeCheck`?

Comment: @TravisBrown I tried it. I am not sure if I use it correctly. If just `c.typeCheck(tree))` where `tree` is Scala AST that contains underscored lambda then this is not helped. `println(s"${showRaw(c.typeCheck(tree))}")` shows me no type of `x$2`.



May I get somehow from `macros.Context` what are arguments types of particular function?

Comment: I.e. having
`val function = Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM | SYNTHETIC), newTermName("x$1"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Int)), EmptyTree), ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM | SYNTHETIC), newTermName("x$2"), TypeTree(), EmptyTree)), Apply(Select(Typed(Ident(newTermName("x$1")), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Int))), newTermName("$plus")), List(Ident(newTermName("x$2")))))`

call `c.inferTypes(function)` that transforms `x$2` to `ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM | SYNTHETIC), newTermName("x$2"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Int)), EmptyTree)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Number ~> ((_:Int) + _)
```

is transformed to something like this

```
pimpActionOp[...](rule).~>.apply[...](function)
```

type classes of `pimpActionOp` and `apply` contain all necessary information to restore types.